# How can I change the text of an element but maintain CSS styling in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace the text of a list element and maintain the stylying of the original class, however, when I replace it overwrites the CSS. When I try add new styling to it it doesn't seem to work. I may be mis-understanding the html() function - can it have styling applied to it?

```
$('#listElement>li:eq(1)').html('replacement text').addClass('.progressStep')

$('.progressStep').css({
   'width': '140px',
   'display': 'block',
   'margin': '10px 0 0 -60px',
   'color': '#c5c5c5'
})
```

Comment: add your markup as well

Comment: can you post the original css which is getting overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed `.progressStep` as argument to `.addClass()`. which is adding class `.progressStep` and not `progressStep`

You do not need to use class selector in `.addClass()` method. you should simply pass classname(s) as an argument. In current case, use `addClass('progressStep')` instead of `addClass('.progressStep')`:

```
$('#listElement>li:eq(1)').html('replacement text').addClass('progressStep')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#listElement>li:eq(1)').text('replacement text').addClass('.progressStep')
```

You only need to use `html` if you're actually adding html

Comment: doesn't matter in his case.